# How to put a newline into a column header in an xtable in R

Tags: r, latex, tex, sweave, xtable

I have a dataframe that I am putting into a [sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) document using xtable, however one of my column names is quite long, and I would like to break it over two lines to save space

```
calqc_table<-structure(list(RUNID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), ANALYTEINDEX = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), ID = structure(1:11, .Label = c("Cal A", "Cal B", "Cal C", 
"Cal D", "Cal E", "Cal F", "Cal G", "Cal H", "Cal High", "Cal Low", 
"Cal Mid"), class = "factor"), mean_conc = c(200.619459644855, 
158.264703128903, 102.469121407733, 50.3551544728544, 9.88296440865076, 
4.41727762501703, 2.53494715706024, 1.00602831741361, 199.065054555735, 
2.48063347296935, 50.1499780776199), sd_conc = c(2.3275711264554, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.101636943231162, 0, 0, 0), nrow = c(3, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("Identifier of the Run within the Study", "ANALYTEINDEX", 
"ID", "mean_conc", "sd_conc", "nrow"), row.names = c(NA, -11L
), class = "data.frame")
calqc_xtable<-xtable(calqc_table)
```

I have tried putting a newline into the name, but this didn't seem to work

```
names(calqc_table)[1]<-"Identifier of the \nRun within the Study"
```

Is there a way to do this ?  I have seen someone suggest using the latex function from the [hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package to manually iterate over the table and write it out in latex manually, including the newline, but this seems like a bit of a faf !

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question and applies to many situations, but in this specific case I might explore ways to reduce wordiness- perhaps "Run Identifier" instead of "Identifier of the Run within the Study"?

Comment: You're right, I conjured up a short example, and my long title is a bit more wordy than my usual....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The best way I have found to do this is to indicate the table column as a "fixed width" column so that the text inside it wraps.  With the `xtable` package, this can be done with:

```
align( calqc_xtable ) <- c( 'l', 'p{1.5in}', rep('c',5) )
```

`xtable` demands that you provide an alignment for the option "rownames" column- this is the initial `l` specification.  The section specification, `p{1.5in}`, is used for your first column header, which is quite long.  This limits it to a box 1.5 inches in width and the header will wrap onto multiple lines if necessary.  The remaining five columns are set centered using the `c` specifier.

One major problem with fixed width columns like `p{1.5in}` is that **they set the text using a justified alignment**.  This causes the inter-word spacing in each line to be expanded such that the line will fill up the entire 1.5 inches allotted.

Frankly, in most cases this produces results which I cannot describe using polite language (I'm an amateur typography nut and this sort of behavior causes facial ticks).

The fix is to provide a latex alignment command by prepending a `>{}` field to the column specification:

```
align( calqc_xtable ) <- c( 'l', '>{\\centering}p{1.5in}', rep('c',4) )
```

Other useful alignment commands are:

- \raggedright -> causes text to be **left aligned**
- \raggedleft  -> causes text to be **right aligned**

Remember to double backslashes to escape them in R strings.  You may also need to disable the string sanitation function that `xtable` uses by default.

**Note**

This alignment technique **will fail** if used on the last column of a table **unless** table rows are ended with `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\`, which I think is not the case with `xtable` and is not easily customizable through any user-settable option.

The other thing to consider is that you may not want the entire column line-wrapped to 1.5 inches and centered- just the header.  In that case, disable `xtable` string sanitization and set your header using a `\multicolumn` cell of width 1:

```
names(calqc_table)[1]<-"\\multicolumn{1}{>{\\centering}p{1.5in}}{Identifier of the Run within the Study}"
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify maximum width for a column? Something like p{<=1.5in}?

Comment: This may be what you have to do, but it is heinous.

Answer (score 2):

@Sharpie 's technique did not work for me, as pandoc failed with error 43 on conversion to pdf. Therefore, here is what I did:

moved the `\\centering` marker:

```
names(calqc_table)=c(rep("\\multicolumn{1}{p{0.75in}}{\\centering Identifier of the Run within the Study}", 6))
```

(here applied to all 6 columns of the table)

and disabled sanitization in xtable printing:

```
print(calqc_table, sanitize.colnames.function=function(x){x})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me: I first save the xtable in a file, then re-import it (as malexan describes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474552/how-to-read-txt-file-and-replace-word-in-r)) and then replace the text which is to be browken into two lines as suggested by egreg [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell). The tricky thing is to geht the escape characters `"\"` right. This is also relevant if the text you want to break into two lines contains characters which are Special Regex Characters (for a list of these see e.g. [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html)) as you need to match them in the "pattern" argument.

Below you can see how the table from the question above can be modified to break the first column name in two lines.

```
  print(calqc_xtable, "calqc_xtable.tex", type = "latex")

   readLines("calqc_xtable.tex") |>
         stringr::str_replace(
         pattern = "Identifier of the Run within the Study", 
         replace = paste("\\\\begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}Identifier of the Run \\\\\\\\ within the Study \\\\end{tabular}")) |>
   writeLines(con = "calqc_xtable.tex")
```

[Screenshot from the resulting LaTex table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SC0c.png)