# Simple example of using tables + knitr for latex

Tags: r, latex, knitr, tables-package

I'm struggling with a [tables](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/tables.pdf) package, all the examples in the packable docs are so complex and none of them works for me with `knitr` and latex. Could somebody help be out and display a simple table with some formulas and multiline labels in the header?

Something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))
colnames(df) <- c("first column", "second \\frac{1}{2}", "third column first line \\ second line")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you dead set on using “tables”? I recommend [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/) in combination with pandoc. It offers fewer options for customisation but it mostly does “the correct thing”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to create multi-line headers for tables in LaTeX using the `xtable` package. These can be compiled from either .Rmd or .Rnw files. Building on the example by mattw and using `add.to.row` in the `print` method for `xtable`:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:50, nrow = 10))

print(
  xtable(df),
  include.rownames = FALSE,
  include.colnames = FALSE,
  add.to.row = list(
    pos = list(0),
    command = c(
      "& \\multicolumn{4}{c}{4 column header} \\\\
       \\cline{2-5}
      col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 \\\\ "
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Note that `add.to.row` requires a list with two elements: pos and command. The first must be a list, the second a character string or vector, see `?print.xtable`. `pos` gives the row number for the LaTeX insertion, and `command` is the insertion. Be a bit careful with formatting this, as it is will run directly into the next cell of the first column if you don't put in spaces or `\n`.

There are lots of options for customisation, allowing you to create quite complex tables with a bit of tweaking.

```
print(
  xtable(df),
  include.rownames = FALSE,
  include.colnames = FALSE,
  hline.after = c(-1,0),
  add.to.row = list(
    pos = list(0,5,10),
    command = c(
      "& \\multicolumn{4}{c}{4 column header} \\\\
       \\cline{2-5}
      col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 \\\\ ",
      "\\hline \\multicolumn{5}{l}{Separator in table.} \\\\ \\hline",
      "\\hline \\multicolumn{5}{l}{Notes at end of table.} \\\\ "
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

In this example I change the default settings for where `xtable` puts `\hline`, allowing me to add the last `\hline` above the notes - useful for explaining superscripts in the table.

Note also the use of `\cline{2-5}` giving me a line over columns 2 - 5.

See [gist](https://gist.github.com/ivyleavedtoadflax/275294b97f4237142a56) for fully reproducible example.

Comment: You wrote "This is achievable in RMarkdown", but then present a LaTeX solution? I'm confused …

Comment: Yes I take your point. I meant it is achievable from a .Rmd, although the underlying basis would be using LaTeX via xtable. I'll adjust my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible with RMarkdown if you want the table to be in LaTeX style. However, you can easily do this with the `xtable` package when you write your code in an `.Rnw` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
library("xtable")
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))
colnames(df) <- c("first column", "second $\\frac{1}{2}$",
                  "third column")
@
<<xtable, results = "asis">>=
print(xtable(df), floating = TRUE,
      sanitize.colnames.function = identity, type = "latex")
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, one more question, is it possible to have a multiline header? I updated the question?

Comment: I haven't done that, yet. I hope that this link can help you a bit: [How to put a newline into a column header in an xtable in R](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2687142/2323832)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I've been here. It does not compile for me with knitr for some reason

Comment: That post is very helpful but as they noted, the alignment techniques used will not work on the last column of a table, making it tough to get all of the columns multi line while having alignment within each.